# How to add new vector to Keras embedding matrix

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, categorical-data, embedding

## Background

I am using an embedding layer for a categorical data column in Keras.
My understanding is that an embedding layer is simply a matrix which consist of trainable vectors, each mapped to an index.

## My problem

After training finished, I want to add a new index-vector pair to the embedding matrix.
(The vector is generated by me, no training involved at this stage.)

How do I do this?
I wish to use the newly added embedding in predictions as well.

## Code

```
keras.layers.Embedding(number_of_categories, embedding_size, input_length=1)
```

I am especially stuck, since number of categories are coded in the model architecture. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you add it during training even if you training data doesn't use it ?

Comment: @AhmedRagab Thank you. You mean something like: if I only have let's say a 1000 categories for that column, use 2000 for number_of_categories in the model, update embedding matrix after training. I'll give it a try and get back to you.